# How to align text in TikZ nodes by baseline?

Tags: tikz-pgf, nodes

I need to draw a graph where some nodes have the same y-coordinate. I want the text within the nodes on the same y-coordinate to be baseline-aligned. However, the text seems to be aligned by the bottom lines, not the baseline.

Here's what I tried to do:

```
\documentclass[final,t]{beamer}
\mode<presentation>
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\tikzstyle{gate2} = [circle,fill=white,draw=black,minimum size=1cm]
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \node[gate2] (mu_0) at (0, 0) {$\mu_0$};
        \node[gate2, baseline = (mu_0.base)] (Lambda_0) at (2,  0) {$\Lambda_0  $};
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

What I see is that the shapes are at the same y-coordinate (as expected), but mu is higher than Lambda. How do I specify that mu and Lambda should be on the baseline?

Comment: You can add `anchor=base` to the `gate2` style. The default anchor is the `center` anchor. If you load the `positioning` library you can do `base right=of mu_0` at the second node. The value of `node distance` is then used as the distance between the nodes. (Unrelated to your actual question: [Should `\tikzset` or `\tikzstyle` be used to define TikZ styles?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/52372))

Comment: `anchor=base` moves the shapes, unfortunately: the circle containing mu becomes lower than the Lambda circle.

Comment: Also, looks like positioning is not available in my environment, alas: adding `\usepackage{positioning}` leads to error `LaTeX Error: File `positioning.sty' not found. [\usepackage]`

Comment: That has something to do that `\mu_0` is not as high as `\Lambda_0` as TikZ positions the boxes containing the text in the center of the shape. You will need to work with `\vphantom{\Lambda}` in the `\mu` node or use `text height` and sometime even `text depth`. — `positioning` is a TikZ library not a LaTeX package, so you need to do `\usetikzlibrary{positioning}`, the problem is still the same though.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

I would just add a `\strut` to both characters

```
\documentclass[final,t]{beamer}
\mode<presentation>
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\tikzstyle{gate2} = [circle,fill=white,draw=black,minimum size=1cm]
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \node[gate2] (mu_0) at (0, 0) {$\strut\mu_0$};
        \node[gate2, baseline = (mu_0.base)] (Lambda_0) at (2,  0) {$\strut\Lambda_0$};
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 23):

Depending on your actual diagram you want to use the TikZ library `positioning` loaded by

```
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
```

and the `base right=of <other node>` key.

Either way, you want to use the `text height` key. You also want to set the `text depth` key for the very same reasons if you have text of different depth (in your case, the `\mu` is lower/deeper than the subscript `0` in both nodes).

If you expect only general characters like A-Za-z0-9 and simple subscripts you can easily use `font=\vphantom{Ag}` which is similar to `font=\strut` but doesn’t add that much height and depth (which you don’t notice as you use `minimum size=1cm` here).

The difference is that the keys `text height` and `text depth` do set the height and depth no matter the content while `\vphantom` and `\strut` only set a minimum height/depth (so to speak).

### Code

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\tikzset{gate2/.style={circle, inner sep=+0pt, fill=white, draw=black, minimum size=+1cm}}
\newcommand*{\tfbox}[1]{{\fboxsep-\fboxrule\fbox{#1}}}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[gate2/.append style={anchor=base}]
  \node[gate2] (mu_0)                {\tfbox{$\mu_0$}};
  \node[gate2] (Lambda_0) at (2,  0) {\tfbox{$\Lambda_0$}};
  \draw (mu_0.center) -- (Lambda_0.center) (mu_0.base)   -- (Lambda_0.base);
\end{tikzpicture}
\begin{tikzpicture}[gate2/.append style={text height=\heightof{$\Lambda$},text depth=\depthof{g}}]
  \node[gate2] (mu_0)                {$\mu_0$};
  \node[gate2] (Lambda_0) at (2,  0) {$\Lambda_0$};
  \draw (mu_0.center) -- (Lambda_0.center) (mu_0.base)   -- (Lambda_0.base);
\end{tikzpicture}
\begin{tikzpicture}[gate2/.append style={font=\vphantom{Ag}}]
  \node[gate2] (mu_0)               {$\mu_0$};
  \node[gate2] (Lambda_0) at (2, 0) {$\Lambda_0$};
  \draw (mu_0.center) -- (Lambda_0.center) (mu_0.base)   -- (Lambda_0.base);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

### Output

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: As you suggested in a comment above, `\vphantom` works well. This solution is also tied to the actual symbols being used; is it better than `\vphantom`?

Comment: I'm just wondering why TikZ doesn't put the text baseline at the shape center. It's quite sensible, IMO.

Comment: @vuvuzela Both solutions have their advantages and disadvantages. If you only use the usual characters like letters and digits you can easily just set `font=\vphantom{Ag}` which works similar to `font=\strut` solution but doesn’t add that much height (`\strut` is higher and deeper than `A` and `g`). But `\vphantom` is not safe when bigger content is used, `text height` and `text depth` set the height and depth no matter what the content (which may also not what you’re after). It really depends on the general content of your nodes. Probably, `font=\vphantom{Ag}` is just fine.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation! I'll go with adding phantom characters for now as a simpler solution, because I haven't got many nodes and the content is always a letter or two.

Answer (score 5):

You can accomplish this by setting fixed text height and text depth settings. I used this piece of code, originally for lining up expressions in commutative diagrams:

```
\tikzstyle{inline text}=[text height=1.5ex, text depth=0.25ex, yshift=0.5mm]
```

but it also seems to work pretty well for other kinds of diagrams.