# TIkz node text not aligned correctly

Tags: tikz-pgf

I have the following code:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix,shapes,arrows,positioning,chains}

\begin{document}

\tikzset{
desicion/.style={
    diamond,
    draw,
    text width=4em,
    text badly centered,
    inner sep=0pt
},
block/.style={
    rectangle,
    draw,
    text width=10em,
    text centered,
    rounded corners
},
cloud/.style={
    draw,
    ellipse,
    minimum height=2em
},
descr/.style={
    fill=white,
    inner sep=2.5pt
},
connector/.style={
    -latex,
    font=\scriptsize
},
rectangle connector/.style={
    connector,
    to path={(\tikztostart) -- ++(#1,0pt) \tikztonodes |- (\tikztotarget) },
    pos=0.5
},
rectangle connector/.default=-2cm, straight connector/.style={
    connector,
    to path=--(\tikztotarget) \tikztonodes}
}

\begin{figure}[htpb]
\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}
      \def\x{1.5}
      \node [block] (init) {Initialisation};
      \node [block, right = 3cm of init] (running) {Running};
      \draw[->] (init) -- (running);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}
\caption{Fonctionnement du programme.}
\label{fig:svnfm-main-flow}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Output:

[image]

As you can see, "Initialisation" and "Running" are not correctly aligned horizontally. How can I change that ? Thank you.

Comment: for start try add `\vphantom{g}` to text in the first node. than see, where you to nodes style definition can add `text depth=0.5ex`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your question is closely related to this one: [How to align text in TikZ nodes by baseline?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/133227/how-to-align-text-in-tikz-nodes-by-baseline)

You could simply add `\strut`s to your text (e.g. `Initialisation\strut`). Or, as mentioned by Zarko and also in answers of the linked question, you could add `text depth=...` and `text height=...` to your `block` style. I would recommend the `\strut` depth and height:

```
text depth=.3\baselineskip,
text height=.7\baselineskip
```

You could try other values or the other possibilities of Qrrbrbirlbel's answer in the linked question.

MWE with the latter solution:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix,shapes,arrows,positioning,chains}

\begin{document}

\tikzset{
desicion/.style={
    diamond,
    draw,
    text width=4em,
    text badly centered,
    inner sep=0pt
},
block/.style={
    rectangle,
    draw,
    text width=10em,
    text centered,
    rounded corners,
    text depth=.3\baselineskip,
    text height=.7\baselineskip
},
cloud/.style={
    draw,
    ellipse,
    minimum height=2em
},
descr/.style={
    fill=white,
    inner sep=2.5pt
},
connector/.style={
    -latex,
    font=\scriptsize
},
rectangle connector/.style={
    connector,
    to path={(\tikztostart) -- ++(#1,0pt) \tikztonodes |- (\tikztotarget) },
    pos=0.5
},
rectangle connector/.default=-2cm, straight connector/.style={
    connector,
    to path=--(\tikztotarget) \tikztonodes}
}

\begin{figure}[htpb]
\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}
      \def\x{1.5}
      \node [block] (init) {\rlap{\rule{9cm}{.5pt}}Initialisation};
      \node [block, right = 3cm of init] (running) {Running};
      \draw[->] (init) -- (running);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}
\caption{Fonctionnement du programme.}
\label{fig:svnfm-main-flow}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Producing:

[image: result]