# aligning letters in tikz pictures

Tags: tikz-pgf

I have a tikz picture with several nodes labelled with a single letter each, like so:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}

  \begin{frame}{my pic}
  \begin{tikzpicture}
   \node at (0,0) (pt) {$p$};
  \node at (.5,0) (at) {$a$};
  \node at (1,0) (zt) {$Z$};
  \end{tikzpicture}
  \end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Apparently, tikz centers the letters vertically over the node, which means that the "p" is too high and the "Z" is too low. Is there an easy way to tell tikz to align the labels with the baseline of the character? I thought about putting "full height" phantom characters left and right of each label (e.g. "j"), but since the picture is quite large, this would be quite a bit of typing, so I'm wondering if there's a more elegant solution

Comment: This has been asked many times.  I'll see whether I can find the duplicate.

Comment: A similar problem was solved in https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/133227/how-to-align-text-in-tikz-nodes-by-baseline

Comment: OK, sorry for the dupe.