# Text baseline alignment in filled boxes using tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf, alignment, baseline

How do I align text in individual boxes to avoid getting results like the following where the second word is shifted up due to parts of the characters stretching below the baseline?

[image]

Here's my MWE:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\pagestyle{empty}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning,calc}

\geometry{papersize={85mm, 15mm}}

\begin{document}

\newcommand\textbox[5]{
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
\filldraw [fill=black, draw=black, line width=0.3mm]
     ($(current page.south west)+(#1,#2)$) rectangle 
     ($(current page.south west)+(#3,#4)$)
     node[pos=0.5] {\color{white}#5};
\end{tikzpicture}}

\textbox{10.0mm}{5mm}{40.0mm}{10.0mm}{\bf{Levels}}
\textbox{45.0mm}{5mm}{75.0mm}{10.0mm}{\bf{Gauging}}

\end{document}
```

I know there is an argument `yshift` but I don't know how to make this work dependent on the text's baseline. Maybe that argument isn't even the right option.

Edited to say: the placement of the word "Levels" looks natural and "Gauging" should be at the same level, meaning the g's can stick out towards the bottom.

Comment: unrelated but `\bf` is not defined by default in latex, and when it is defined (for compatibility with documents written in the 1980s) the syntax is `{\bf Levels}` not `\bf{Levels}`  use `\textbf{levels}`

Comment: OK, thanks for the hint.

Comment: you could use `\strut#5` so they always aligned as if they had a descender

Comment: If I use `\strut%5` then they align. However, both of the words are shifted up. I think it looks more natural if it is placed like the word "Levels". So in case of "Gauging", the g's should be sticking out to the bottom.

Comment: In terms of the `\strut` approach, here is the related question: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/133227/how-to-align-text-in-tikz-nodes-by-baseline

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First, as David Carlisle [said](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/1090/david-carlisle), you should not use `\bf` in LaTeX (plus, it doesn't take an argument, it is what Leslie Lamport would call a *declaration*: it acts on whatever follows in the current TeX group). I replaced it with `font=\normalfont\bfseries` in the node options.

You have texts of different depths, but you presumably want the black rectangles to have exactly the same height. Since you said in [a comment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/525599/text-baseline-alignment-in-filled-boxes-using-tikz#comment1329485_525599) that you would like vertical placement to be the same as for `Levels`, which has no descender, I propose to ignore the depth of the texts passed to your `\textbox` macro. This can be done either with Ti*k*Z options or with box manipulation commands provided by (La)TeX.

## Ti*k*Zy ways

### Using Ti*k*Z nodes for the black rectangles

Here, we use a Ti*k*Z node with `rectangle` shape to draw each text as well as the black rectangle behind it (in your solution, the black rectangles were drawn with a `rectangle` *operation*, not a node). For cleanliness and readability of the code, we define a Ti*k*Z style named `my special node` that contains all options needed for these special nodes. The most important options in this style in relation to your question are:

- `text depth=0pt` in order to ignore the depth of the node contents when computing its dimensions;
- `anchor=south west` to place the node by giving the coordinates of its lower left corner;
- `font=\normalfont\bfseries` to select the font;
- `minimum width` and `minimum height` so that the rectangles are at least as wide and high as mandated by the arguments of your `\textbox` macro;
- `inner sep=0pt` to ensure that no more space is automatically added inside the node, around its contents (with a larger value, the node contents could “push” its border even when not touching it; this can be desirable in some way, but may also easily result in nodes with different heights if the contents of a node is higher than that of other nodes) .

You don't really need `line width=0.3mm` (you could use `0pt`) nor the `-0.5\pgflinewidth` in the `xshift` and `yshift` amounts used for the node. The only reason I include them is to provide an *exact match* with your example (for the `line width`) and with the TeXnical method given below. With the following code, the Ti*k*Z `calc` and `positioning` libraries are not needed at all.

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[papersize={85mm, 15mm}]{geometry}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{tikz}

\pagestyle{empty}

\tikzset{
  my special node/.style n args={4}{
    line width=0.3mm, draw=black, fill=black, text=white,
    inner sep=0pt, text depth=0pt, anchor=south west, font=\normalfont\bfseries,
    minimum width={(#3)-(#1)}, minimum height={(#4)-(#2)},
  }
}

\begin{document}

\newcommand{\textbox}[5]{%
  \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay]
  \node[my special node={#1}{#2}{#3}{#4}]
    at ([xshift={(#1)-0.5\pgflinewidth}, yshift={(#2)-0.5\pgflinewidth}]%
        current page.south west) {#5};
  \end{tikzpicture}%
}

\textbox{10.0mm}{5mm}{40.0mm}{10.0mm}{Levels}
\textbox{45.0mm}{5mm}{75.0mm}{10.0mm}{Gauging}

\end{document}
```

[image: screenshot]

Cropped screenshot:

[image]

Proof that both texts have the same baseline:

[image: screenshot with added rule]

One nice thing when your rectangles are Ti*k*Z nodes is that you can use many Ti*k*Z tools to work with them: name nodes, place nodes relatively to other ones, connect nodes, drop shadows, etc. For instance, with the above code, you only need to add `\usetikzlibrary{shadows}` and the `drop shadow` node option to obtain this:

[image: Example with a “drop shadow”]

### Using the `rectangle` operation

@Schrödinger'scat proposed another nice Ti*k*Zy solution that is very close to your code and produces the exact same output as my two methods given above and below. This method uses the `rectangle` operation to draw the black rectangles, as opposed to filling the rectangle nodes containing the texts from the fifth argument of `\textbox`.

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[papersize={85mm, 15mm}]{geometry}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{tikz}

\pagestyle{empty}

\begin{document}

\newcommand*{\textbox}[5]{%
  \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay]
  \filldraw [fill=black, draw=black, line width=0.3mm]
    (current page.south west)+(#1,#2) rectangle +(#3,#4)
    node[pos=0.5, font=\normalfont\bfseries, text depth=0pt, text=white] {#5};
  \end{tikzpicture}%
}

\textbox{10.0mm}{5mm}{40.0mm}{10.0mm}{Levels}
\textbox{45.0mm}{5mm}{75.0mm}{10.0mm}{Gauging}

\end{document}
```

The output is exactly the same as above.

## TeXnical way

Here, instead of using `text depth=0pt` for the nodes containing the boxed texts, we use a short macro that puts its argument in a box, sets the box depth to zero and outputs the box. This implies that again, TeX will ignore the depth of the argument when determining the vertical extent of the Ti*k*Z node contents.

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[papersize={85mm, 15mm}]{geometry}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\pagestyle{empty}

\newsavebox{\mybox}

\newcommand*{\killboxdepth}[1]{%
  \sbox{\mybox}{#1}%
  \dp\mybox=0pt \box\mybox
}

\begin{document}

\newcommand*{\textbox}[5]{%
  \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay]
  \filldraw [fill=black, draw=black, line width=0.3mm]
    ($(current page.south west)+(#1,#2)$) rectangle
    ($(current page.south west)+(#3,#4)$)
    node[pos=0.5, font=\normalfont\bfseries] {\color{white}\killboxdepth{#5}};
  \end{tikzpicture}%
}

\textbox{10.0mm}{5mm}{40.0mm}{10.0mm}{Levels}
\textbox{45.0mm}{5mm}{75.0mm}{10.0mm}{Gauging}

\end{document}
```

The output is exactly the same as in the Ti*k*Zy ways.

Note: another way to define `\killboxdepth` is the following:

```latex
\newcommand{\killboxdepth}{%
  \raisebox{0pt}[\height][0pt]%
}
```

This is a bit more LaTeXish than using the `\dp` and `\box` commands, which are TeX primitives. As @barbarabeeton pointed out, yet another way—assuming `amsmath` is loaded—would be to use `\smash[b]` instead of `\killboxdepth` (then this macro isn't necessary). There is definitely more than one way to do it!

Comment: This is it and it's perfect! Many thanks for the solution, frougon. I don't think a different strategy is needed.

Comment: @Hansel Glad to hear that. :-) I added a method that is more Ti*k*Zy and gives exactly the same output.

Comment: Maybe also add `\newcommand*{\textbox}[5]{%
  \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay]
  \filldraw [fill=black, draw=black, line width=0.3mm]
    (current page.south west)+(#1,#2) rectangle
    +(#3,#4)
    node[pos=0.5, font=\normalfont\bfseries,text depth=0pt,text=white] 
 {#5};
  \end{tikzpicture}%
}
`.

Comment: @Schrödinger'scat Thanks for your suggestion! I've incorporated your solution too. I had tried with `text=white` when working on the chronologically first version—the TeXnical one—and it didn't work (I guess the `\sbox` doesn't see the `text=white`?). But it does work with your code and also with my Ti*k*Zy method, which doesn't use `\sbox`.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the other options and especially for the addition of a detailed description. I am sure this will help others facing the same issue in the future.

Comment: @Hansel I added an example showing why I think that the black-rectangles-are-filled-nodes approach is very convenient: it makes it trivial to add effects like “drop shadows.”

Comment: You don't mention what I consider the easiest approach.  If the text is a single line, `\smash[b]`.

Comment: @barbarabeeton Sorry, but I don't think this is satisfactory. `\smash` not only makes the depth equal to zero, it also does that for the height, which ruins the result here ([screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rD2t9.png)). I could add a zero-width rule to give the height that `\smash` kills, but then it certainly wouldn't be simpler. I added a way using `\raisebox` though, which is about as simple as the one based on `\sbox`, `\dp` and `\box`.

Comment: I said `\smash[b]`, which is "bottom smash".  Of course a "full" smash is inappropriate.

Comment: @barbarabeeton Sorry, I misread that because I didn't know `amsmath` redefined `\smash`. Indeed, `\smash[b]` can do the job here, but it requires one to load `amsmath`; therefore, I think the `\raisebox` way I added is (slightly) preferable, since it is as simple and only requires the LaTeX kernel. There is more than one way to do it...

Comment: @barbarabeeton `\smash[b]` is mentioned in the last version of the answer, thanks for the info.

Comment: Thanks.  (I come from an environment where `amsmath` is *always* assumed to be loaded -- it's built into the AMS document classes -- so I instinctively don't assume that it's not there.)