# Lining up text across different Tikz rectangles

Tags: tikz-pgf

I have a few rectangles that hold text made in Tikz next to eachother, and I want them to all be properly aligned vertically. The issue is that for boxes that hold words with letters such as j and y, the bottom of the box is extended and so the boxes with words that don't contain those letters are slightly higher, like so:
[image]

Word and Box are higher than the other three, I would like them to all be at the same height. The command I am using to generate this is

```
\newcommand{\autour}[1]{\tikz[baseline=(X.base)]\node [fill=seafoam,rectangle,inner sep=5pt, anchor=text, rounded corners=5pt, minimum height=0.7cm] (X) {#1};}

\autour{\textcolor{white}{\textbf{June}}}
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Perhaps a duplicate of this: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/133227/how-to-align-text-in-tikz-nodes-by-baseline, in which `\strut` may be used, as in `\newcommand{\autour}[1]{\tikz[baseline=(X.base)]\node [fill=magenta,rectangle,inner sep=5pt, anchor=text, rounded corners=5pt, minimum height=0.7cm] (X) {\strut#1};}`

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes Using a strut made it work perfectly, thank you!

Comment: This should probably be an answer …

Answer (score 1):

An alternative construction with `tcolorbox`. It uses `\strut` solution as proposed by Steven B. Segletes.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}

\newtcbox{\autor}[1][]{%
on line, size=fbox, arc=2mm, colback=violet, colupper=white, 
colframe=violet, before upper={\strut}
}

\begin{document}
This a list: \autor{June} \autor{Objective} \autor{Rhythm} \autor{Word} \autor{Box}
\end{document}
```

[image]