# TikZ - LuaLaTeX - Trying to fix the library `phylogenetics`

Tags: tikz-pgf, positioning, tikz-styles

The following code shows an ugly way to fix the bad vertical positioning of the labels in a top-down phylogenetic graph. How to avoid the special fixing style done by hand? How to find the good style to be fixed?

[image]

```
% Source: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/133237/6880

\documentclass[12 pt]{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{graphs, graphdrawing}
\usegdlibrary{phylogenetics}

\pgfgdset{
    phylogenetic inner node/.style = {
        /tikz/.cd, 
        draw, circle, 
        inner sep=0pt, 
        minimum size=5pt
    }
}


\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\graph[
    phylogenetic tree layout,
    upgma,
    distance matrix = {
      % a b c d e f g
        0 4 9 9 9 9 9 % a 
        4 0 9 9 9 9 9 % b
        9 9 0 2 7 7 7 % c
        9 9 2 0 7 7 7 % d
        9 9 7 7 0 3 5 % e
        9 9 7 7 3 0 5 % f
        9 9 7 7 5 5 0 % g
    }]
    { a, b, c, d, e, f, g }; 
\end{tikzpicture}



\begin{tikzpicture}[
    test/.append style={font=\vphantom{Vg}}
]
\graph[
    phylogenetic tree layout,
    upgma,
    distance matrix = {
      % a b c d e f g
        0 4 9 9 9 9 9 % a 
        4 0 9 9 9 9 9 % b
        9 9 0 2 7 7 7 % c
        9 9 2 0 7 7 7 % d
        9 9 7 7 0 3 5 % e
        9 9 7 7 3 0 5 % f
        9 9 7 7 5 5 0 % g
    }]
    { a[test], b[test], c[test], d[test], e[test], f[test], g[test] }; 
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set the option `text height` for `every node` so something sensible (additionally, depending on the use case, setting `text depth` is also a good idea):

```
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{graphs, graphdrawing}
\usegdlibrary{phylogenetics}

\pgfgdset{
    phylogenetic inner node/.style={
        /tikz/.cd, draw, circle, inner sep=0pt, minimum size=5pt
    }
}

\tikzset{
    every node/.style={text height=1.25ex}
}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \graph[phylogenetic tree layout,
       upgma,
       distance matrix = {
        0 4 9 9 9 9 9 
        4 0 9 9 9 9 9
        9 9 0 2 7 7 7 
        9 9 2 0 7 7 7 
        9 9 7 7 0 3 5 
        9 9 7 7 3 0 5
        9 9 7 7 5 5 0 }]
{ a, b, c, d, e, f, g }; 
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

---

Why does this help here? You can best see the effect by temporarily adding a border to the nodes:

```
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{graphs, graphdrawing}
\usegdlibrary{phylogenetics}

\pgfgdset{
    phylogenetic inner node/.style={
        /tikz/.cd, draw, circle, inner sep=0pt, minimum size=5pt
    }
}

\tikzset{
    every node/.style={text height=1.5ex, text depth=0.33ex, draw}
}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \graph[phylogenetic tree layout,
       upgma,
       distance matrix = {
        0 4 9 9 9 9 9 
        4 0 9 9 9 9 9
        9 9 0 2 7 7 7 
        9 9 2 0 7 7 7 
        9 9 7 7 0 3 5 
        9 9 7 7 3 0 5
        9 9 7 7 5 5 0 }]
{ a, b, c, d, e, f, g }; 
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Without `text depth` set:

[image]

Without `text height` (and without `text depth`) set:

[image]

Comment: Using it via `\begin{tikzpicture}[every node/.style={text height=1.25ex}] ... \end{tikzpicture}` does the job. Thanks.

Comment: @projetmbc Sure, this is also a way to go. I added some pictures to show what is happening and why setting `text height` and `text depth` helps in this case.